# Select and Set not working together in TSQL FUNCTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a function in `SQL SERVER` and setting a user variable using select and after that set . But seems set is not working .

```
--@id is input
Declare @result varchar(MAX)
        SELECT @result = INFO FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID= +''+'DOMAIN\'+@id+''
        IF @result IS NULL
            SET @result = 'DOMAIN\'+@id+''      
    return (@result)
```

If user is not found I want to select id not the null values. Buts seems it coming null always 
Set is not working in conditional statement.
What I am doing wrong?

Below is the update:

yes Slippery, I checked its coming null. If I set

```
SET @result ='MY ID'
```

it works but `@result = 'DOMAIN\'+@id` did not work

The whole function

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[USER_INFO] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @id varchar(300)
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
     Declare @result varchar(MAX)
            SELECT @result = INFO FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID= +''+'DOMAIN\'+@id+''
            IF @result IS NULL
                SET @result = 'DOMAIN\'+@id+''      
        return (@result)
END
```

Comment: Are you sure `@id` is not null?

Comment: Set and select seems to be working correctly like this. Like Slippery Pete mentioned are you sure that the ID you are passing in is not null? because this query works correctly.

Comment: @ItalianStallion - `==` is invalid in sql server. `=` is equality, and `!=`/`<>` is inequality.

Comment: Can you show the whole proc/function, and how you're calling it?  `@id` looks to be out of scope here...

Comment: @Sumit Tiwari it seems like you need to handle the ID not coming in null or what value you would like it to be if it is null.

Comment: @JiggsJedi.. I think so its scoping problem. Could you please help me on this. Please ignore the last quotes

Comment: The comments below indicate your table/function are named the same -- thus, you're calling the function wrong.  Am I reading that right?? Show us how you call this function, and the table w/ data.  We're guessing at this point because you haven't told us the whole story.

Comment: @JiggsJedi sorry my function name is FN_USER_INFRO and calling select dbo.FN_USER_INFO(id) from USER_INFO

Comment: Show us some sample data please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case that really is the entire function, you'll need that first line to be "CREATE FUNCTION" (or "ALTER FUNCTION" if it already exists), instead of just "FUNCTION"...

This will eliminate NULL's from being returned by your function:

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)
    -- Eliminate NULL being passed in so string concatenation doesn't return NULL
    IF @id IS NULL
        SET @id = ''
    -- Set the output value...if nothing exists, set it to 'x'
    SET @result = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(INFO,'x') FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID = 'DOMAIN\' + @id);
    -- Now, neither @result OR @id will be NULL so the following should always return something other than NULL
    IF @result = 'x'
            SET @result = 'DOMAIN\' + @id
RETURN (@result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other comments, try this:

```
Declare @result varchar(MAX)
        SELECT @result = INFO FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID= 'DOMAIN\'+@id
        IF @result IS NULL
            SET @result = 'DOMAIN\'+ ISNULL(@id, '')      
    return (@result)
```

I don't think you need all that handing with the quotes and pluses

Comment: Something I found is that @id is coming null..may be scoping issuess?

Comment: NOt able to get rid off this :(

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this. No need of those extra `''` single quotes at end

```
Declare @result varchar(MAX)
        SELECT @result = INFO FROM USER_INFO WHERE ID= 'DOMAIN\' + @id
        IF @result IS NULL
            SET @result = 'DOMAIN\' + @id     
    return (@result)
```

Few points to mention: your function name and the table name both are same `user_info`. Try naming them differently like

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_USER_INFO] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @id varchar(300)
)

SELECT @result = INFO FROM USER_INFO
```

Also, you should call your function like

```
select dbo.Get_USER_INFO('my-user_id')
```

Comment: How you are calling the function? I mean what you are passing to `@id`?

Comment: SELECT functnName(ID) from USER_INFO

Comment: what? that's wrong. you should rather call it like `select dbo.func_name('my_id')`. Moreover, why you are naming your function same as the table. I mean Both your func and table are named as `user_info`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between select and set is that if set didn't found any value then it will return null but if select didn't found any value then it will show the previous value of the variable, the same case is happening for you when the @result value is null select don't assign any value and return the same previous value instead of assigning null and that is the reason the if statement is false and its not moving to the Set statement.

koppinjo, if the @result variable never set to anything then it should hit the block, but i guess the first time the @result variable value is not null so it's not hitting the block.
please view this for post more clarification.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1888/when-to-use-set-vs-select-when-assigning-values-to-variables-in-sql-server/

Comment: In this case though, the @result variable is declared but never set to anything.  It is null by default so whether he is using set or select, the if block should get hit.

Comment: In your post you say that "...select don't assign any value and return the same previous value instead of assigning null..." but at this point, the "previous value" is NULL.  So, in this implementation SET and SELECT will do the same thing.  The difference would be of interest IF "@result" was set to a string literal/some value prior to the "SELECT @result = ..."